# Validating 'other' field only if dropdown value is 'other'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Slightly complicated one to explain, but a very common use case.

I have this  field on my page:

```
<select class="form-control" name="how_you_heard_about_us" id="select-hearaboutus">
```

All of the options within it have names, including this one:

```
<option value="Other">Other</option>
```

I also have a text input, which is only required if the user selects 'Other'.

Here's my condensed validation code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required|max:20',
    'last_name' => 'required|max:20',
    'how_you_heard_about_us' => 'required'
]);
```

I'm trying to set it up, so that the user is only required to enter into the text field, if the dropdown is set to 'other'.

How can I conditionally require the free text field, in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: use required_if

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [`required_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-if) rule:

```
'your_text_field' => 'required_if:how_you_heard_about_us,Other'
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I thought it would be required_if, but couldn't figure out how to use it properly.