# Laravel validation blade syntax

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a dropdown like this 
[image: Dropdown list]

How could i sent the option selected on dropdown into database? I need blade syntax to send them.
Here is my piece of code for validation:

**FrontController**

```
public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'jenis' => 'required|string',
            'kategori' => 'required|string',
            'nopol' => 'required|string',

        ]);

        DB::table('park')->insert([
            'jenis' => $request->input('jenis'),
            'kategori' => $request->input('kategori'),
            'nopol' => $request->input('nopol'),
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'status' => true;

        ]);

    }
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Jenis Kendaraan</label>
  <div class="controls">
       <select id="opt" name="jenis">
          <option value="1">Motor</option>
          <option value="2">Mobil</option>
       </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Should i use @foreach or directly use @if @else @endif ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating 'other' field only if dropdown value is 'other'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705355/validating-other-field-only-if-dropdown-value-is-other)

Comment: Not clear to me... Do you mean you need to populate your dropdown with items from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to save jenis with value either 'Motor' or 'Mobile' because you are validating as a string. Just put as

```
 <select id="opt" name="jenis">
      <option value="Motor">Motor</option>
      <option value="Mobil">Mobil</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you write in value will go in the request object.

`<option value="1">Motor</option>`

this what you wrote in the value , so on the form submission in request()->input('jenis') you will get 1.. you should give numeric validation or between(range) type of validation, please check the laravel docs.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbled upon this via Googling how to validate actual Blade syntax, check this out.

Create a custom validation rule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class BladeSyntax implements Rule
{
    private $message;

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        File::put(resource_path('views/validation.blade.php'), $value);

        try {
            view('validation')->render();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->message = $exception->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return explode('(', $this->message)[0];
    }
}
```

Then use `new BladeSyntax` in your validation rules.